# Checking if "matrix-style" constructions are rings or ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ideals

I am considering rings of the form
$$ \begin{pmatrix} M_{11} & \cdots & M_{1n} \\ \vdots & & \vdots \\  M_{n1} & \cdots & M_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$$
with $M_{ij}$ being either just $0$ or some fixed field (or ring) $F$ (I will call them "matrix-style"). Some of these constructions actually are a ring (not necessarily with a $1$) by elementwise addition and matrix-multiplication, e.g.
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ F & F & 0 \\ F & 0 & F \end{pmatrix}$$
is a ring and 
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & F \\ 0 & F & 0 \\ F & 0 & F \end{pmatrix}$$
is not a ring. It is quite easy to see if such a construction is a ring by multiplying two general matrices and checking if it is still of this form.
However, I wonder if there is an easier way to see if such a construction is a ring without having to check manually? Conversely is there a criterion which shows that certain constructions cannot be rings? (I have checked all possible $3\times 3$ "matrix-style" rings on the computer and I do not see any patterns.)

More generally given such a "matrix-style" ring, is it possible to describe "matrix-style" (left/right) ideals of this ring (of course one could again check this manually)?

Comment: What sort of description are you thinking about? If your ring is not null, then this is true (it is closed under multiplication) if and only if whenever you have a $0$ in a given field, then for any corresponding pair in the row and column of your entry, at least one is zero. If your ring is null, then it is always a ring (a null one). But I guess it amounts to manual checking. I don't think you can expect a better description (but I might be wrong).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For instance for "matrix-style" ideals in such a "matrix-style" ring one could start with quite "sparse" ideals and add them together to get more and more complicated ones.